# Wrong values after returning from function c++

Tags: c++, function, file

My function reads data from file and it works well, but when I return data something goes wrong. This is how it looks like:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxtWD.jpg)

Code:

```
struct csvh
{
//struct declaration
};


float glowa_csv(csvh CSVHead, float EndOfHead)
{
    ifstream obraz;
    obraz.open("POP_OCT.csv", ios::binary);
    //wczytywanie naglowka
    obraz.read(CSVHead.data, sizeof(CSVHead.data)-1); 
    obraz >> CSVHead.lateral_range;
    obraz.read(CSVHead.lat_px_size, sizeof(CSVHead.lat_px_size)-1);
    obraz >> CSVHead.lateral_pxsize;
    ... ( and so on)

    EndOfHead=obraz.tellg();
    obraz.close();

    cout << CSVHead.data<<endl<<CSVHead.godzina<<(rest of variables)<<endl;

    return CSVHead.lateral_range, CSVHead.lateral_pxsize, (...), EndOfHead;
} 

int main()
{
    float EndOfHead;
    csvh CSVHead;

    glowa_csv(CSVHead, EndOfHead);

    system("Pause");
    system("cls");
    cout << CSVHead.data<<endl<<CSVHead.godzina<<(...)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you cannot return multiple values from a function like

```
return CSVHead.lateral_range, CSVHead.lateral_pxsize, (...), EndOfHead;
```

This winds up only returning `EndOfHead` thanks to the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).  What it looks like you want to do is pass `CSVHead` and `EndofHead` by reference so that the function modifies the variables you pass to it and the changes are reflected in `main()`.  You can change the function to

```
void glowa_csv(csvh &CSVHead, float &EndOfHead)
```

And get rid of the return statement entierly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return multiple values from a function you must either return a class/struct or pass the variables by reference.

Passing by reference is perfectly valid but can be confusing for some people, so returning a complex object might be the "better" solution. You can return values in Tuple:

```
std::tuple<int,int,int> method(int input)
{
  /* do your stuff here */

  return { errorCode , value1 , value2 };
}
```

so you don't have to create extra types. Obviously the exact types in the tuple will depend on what you need to return